# import firebase from "firebase" module not working in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js, npm-install

**it showing error like this**

.

```
/firebase.js:2:0
Module not found: Package path . is not exported from package C:\Users\krish\Desktop\FACEBOOK _CLONE\facebook_clone\node_modules\firebase (see exports field in C:\Users\krish\Desktop\FACEBOOK _CLONE\facebook_clone\node_modules\firebase\package.json)
Did you mean './firebase'?
Requests that should resolve in the current directory need to start with './'.
Requests that start with a name are treated as module requests and resolve within module directories (node_modules).
If changing the source code is not an option there is also a resolve options called 'preferRelative' which tries to resolve these kind of requests in the current directory too.
  1 | 
> 2 | import firebase from 'firebase'
  3 | import 'firebase/firestore'
  4 | 
  5 | 

Import trace for requested module:
./Components\InputBox.js
./Components\Feed.js
./pages\index.js

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
```

**firebase config code**

```
import firebase from 'firebase'
import 'firebase/firestore'


// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "fasdfsadfdsafjsafsafsfsfsfsfs",
    authDomain: "facebook-clone-13234.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "facebook-clone-13234",
    storageBucket: "facebook-clone-13234.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "76247424324242",
    appId: "1:762470571881:web:20a2432424324424324424",
    measurementId: "G-9RDT591EEG",
};

const app = !firebase.apps.length
    ? firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
    : firebase.app();

const db = app.firestore();
const storage = firebase.storage();

export  {db,storage};
```

**package.json file i have already installed firebase using npm install firebase**

```
{
  "name": "facebook_clone",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@heroicons/react": "^1.0.4",
    "firebase": "^9.0.0",
    "firebase-tools": "^9.16.6",
    "next": "11.1.0",
    "next-auth": "^3.29.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.3.3",
    "eslint": "7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "11.1.0",
    "postcss": "^8.3.6",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.2.8"
  }
}
```

i was building a facebook clone using reactjs,nextjs and tailwind css .also inorder to add images i need to use firebase. installed firebase using npm install firebase and after importing firebase from "firebase" it shows error

Comment: try this `import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
`

Comment: @Krishnadev.V does answer help you?

Comment: If you wish to use the new modular SDK `import {initializeApp} from "firebase/app"` or `import firebase from "firebase/compat/app"` to keep using older namespaced version. You can checkout the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup) for detailed setup.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this :

```
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
```

instead of:

```
import firebase from 'firebase'
```

Answer (score 4):

Import this way

```
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
```