# Firebase web 9.0.1 error Package path . is not exported

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-platform, electron

I've installed `firebase@9.0.1`, using yarn. The package seems working fine but it gives an error just after running `yarn install` as given.

```sh
Module not found: Error: Package path . is not exported from package /Users/trinity/Projects/hello/node_modules/firebase (see exports field in /Users/trinity/Projects/hello/node_modules/firebase/package.json)
```

Just for reference, attaching the installed set of libraries here.

```sh
➜  hello git:(main) ✗ yarn list --depth=0 | grep firebase
├─ @firebase/analytics-compat@0.1.1
├─ @firebase/analytics-types@0.7.0
├─ @firebase/analytics@0.7.0
├─ @firebase/app-check-compat@0.1.1
├─ @firebase/app-check-interop-types@0.1.0
├─ @firebase/app-check@0.4.0
├─ @firebase/app-compat@0.1.1
├─ @firebase/app-types@0.7.0
├─ @firebase/app@0.7.0
├─ @firebase/auth-compat@0.1.1
├─ @firebase/auth-interop-types@0.1.6
├─ @firebase/auth-types@0.11.0
├─ @firebase/auth@0.17.1
├─ @firebase/component@0.5.6
├─ @firebase/database-compat@0.1.0
├─ @firebase/database-types@0.9.0
├─ @firebase/database@0.12.0
├─ @firebase/firestore-compat@0.1.1
├─ @firebase/firestore-types@2.5.0
├─ @firebase/firestore@3.0.1
├─ @firebase/functions-compat@0.1.1
├─ @firebase/functions-types@0.5.0
├─ @firebase/functions@0.7.0
├─ @firebase/installations@0.5.0
├─ @firebase/logger@0.2.6
├─ @firebase/messaging-compat@0.1.0
├─ @firebase/messaging-interop-types@0.1.0
├─ @firebase/messaging@0.9.0
├─ @firebase/performance-compat@0.1.0
├─ @firebase/performance-types@0.1.0
├─ @firebase/performance@0.5.0
├─ @firebase/polyfill@0.3.36
├─ @firebase/remote-config-compat@0.1.0
├─ @firebase/remote-config-types@0.2.0
├─ @firebase/remote-config@0.2.0
├─ @firebase/storage-compat@0.1.1
├─ @firebase/storage-types@0.6.0
├─ @firebase/storage@0.8.1
├─ @firebase/util@1.3.0
├─ @firebase/webchannel-wrapper@0.5.1
├─ firebase@9.0.1
➜  hello git:(main) ✗
```

The development environment is an electron, I'm using [ERB template](https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate) for the project. Yarn installs the dependency fine, the problem appears in the post-install script. Please leave any clue for resolution. Thanks

Comment: It seems there's no issue on my end adding firebase using `yarn add firebase` then `yarn install`. How to reproduce this issue? Maybe you can give more details on this question.

Comment: @JMGelilio updated the question, please check.

Comment: Have you been able to resolve this? Could be related to my issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69054603/error-package-path-compat-is-not-exported-from-package

Comment: No solution so far :(

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

`import * as firebase from "firebase/app"`

Found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68984595/903000

Comment: in my case this solution compiled ok, but firebase.auth was unreachable.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error, and I realized there was a name conflict because I named one of my folders "firebase". I changed it to some other thing and then the error was gone.